# GTX 770, is it dead?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I was playing a game last night and all was going well until both of my monitors lost signal (both attached to my GTX 770 2GB).

I was heading off anyway so I shut the PC down and thought I would see how it works the next day. I booted up the PC today and it was using the integrated VGA chipset and defaulting to 800x600 resolution. I removed the monitors from the dedicated card and put one into the VGA slot so I could get back my 1080p.

Device manager is reporting an error 43 for the card (Windows stopped this device as it was reporting problems).

I have tried to update the drivers using GeForce experience. My current driver is 384.76 and GeForce experience reports an update is available (384.94). However, when I install this update and reboot, it still reports the same update is available. The install process says it has installed but it hasn't.

I have also tried removing all drivers (from Program Files -> Removed all nvidia options, restarted and installed latest driver).

None of the above has worked, device manager still reports error 43, which I have heard is a driver issue?

I have enough power going to it (G750M) and this happened out of the blue while playing a game (no warning, nominal temps (~70c)).

Is it dead or is this indeed a driver issue that can be fixed?

Comment: Do you have another system you can test the card in? If you move it to another computer and still have the same problem, it is likely there is an issue with your card. Otherwise, it may just be drivers.

Comment: I don't have another PC I can test this with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Device manager still reports error 43, which I have heard is a driver issue?

Indeed Error 43 can be a driver issue. [Lifewire](https://www.lifewire.com/g00/43-errors-explained-2619238?i10c.referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F) says that

> A Code 43 error is generated when Device Manager stops a hardware device because the hardware reported to Windows that it's having some kind of unspecified problem.
>
> This extremely generic message could mean there's a true hardware issue or it could simply mean that there's a driver problem that Windows isn't seeing as such but that the hardware is being affected by.

One way to resolve this is to go to Device Manager, right Click the problem Device and select uninstall. Once done that, click on **Scan for Hardware Changes**. This will automatically reinstall your device.

---

If you do not feel comfortable uninstalling and reinstalling the device manually you can try one of the many available driver updating software.

---

**Edit**: There is a post on the [Nvidia forum](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/861231/nvidia-amp-windows-10-how-i-solved-the-code-43-error-/) regarding this issue, that is worth reading, and giving it a try if above fails. The link from Lifewire offers  a troubleshooting guide as well. However, I would do that if everything else failed

Now if everything fails, do as @HeroCC suggested, try the GPU on another machine. Even if you don't have a second PC at home, I am sure one of your relatives or friends have one that you can test it on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried uninstalling and scanning for changes with Device manager and that didn't help. I have just done a clean install of windows 10 but that also didn't help. I will read the articles you provided, thanks

Comment: @CarlMarkham Then you should add these details to your question. If you did a clean install on windows then I cannot see that this might be a driver issue. Unless it is the specific driver issue as in the Nvidia link says

Comment: I have tried everything but the issue seems to be hardware related. The card itself is around 5 years old so I have resigned and will be getting a new one soon. I will mark this as answered as you provide a decent amount of information which others may find helpful.

Comment: @CarlMarkham sad to hear that.